# Speed of particles

Tags: particles, emission

I am making a ripple water animation in Blender 2.92.

Everything is looking really good, but I have a problem: The droplet falling into the water falls really slow!.
No matter how I tweak and look online, I can not figure out how to speed up the water droplet falling from the emitter.

Help please

TORO

Answer (score 0):

There are several possibilities:

- you could "temporary" increase gravity (e.g. by keyframing)
- you could animate the emitter so the water has some "starting speed"
- you could use inflow instead of geometry and keyframe "use flow" and give some "initial velocity"